# Qual è il significato di "appoggiare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *Moralità del cieco e dello storpio* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto queste parole che il personaggio dello storpio indirizza al cieco:

> **Appoggia** un poco a manca... No! Esagerato! Quella è una virata... Butta l'ancora e torna indietro... Bene... fuori i remi, su le vele... raddrizza, raddrizza... Bene, vieni sicuro adesso.

Non capisco il senso del verbo "appoggiare" in questo passaggio. Ho cercato alla voce "appoggiare" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho saputo trovare nulla al riguardo. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ambito marinaro il termine [appoggiare](http://www.barcaitalia.it/vocabolario.php) significa

> **Poggiare** 
> manovra atta a modificare la rotta allontanando la prua dalla
>   direzione del vento; ci si "appoggia" al vento per fare muovere l'imbarcazione; contrario di orzare.

Nel passaggio da te citato lo storpio dice al cieco di modificare la sua "rotta" spostandosi leggermente a manca (cioè a sinistra).

Per dare un po' più di contesto:

> **CIECO** Seguita a parlare che mi orizzonto... vado bene in questa
>   direzione?
>  **STORPIO** Sì, vieni tranquillo che sei sulla rotta giusta.
>   
> **CIECO** Per non inciampare è meglio che mi metta a gattoni (a quattro
>   zampe). Ehilà, vado sempre dritto? 
> **STORPIO** Appoggia un po' a
>   sinistra... no, esagerato! Quella è una virata... Getta l'ancora e
>   torna indietro... bene... fuori i remi, su le vele... raddrizza,
>   raddrizza... bene, vieni sicuro adesso. 
> **CIECO** Mi hai preso per un
>   galeone? Allungami una mano quando ti sono appresso (vicino). 
> **STORPIO**
>   Ma te le allungo tutt'e due le mani! Vieni, vieni, bel bambino della
>   tua mamma, che ci sei... No! sacramento... non andare via di deriva...
>   raddrizza a destra... Oh, il mio barcone di salvataggio...

Comment: Vedi anche **Francesco Corazzini**, *Vocabolario nautico italiano con le voci corrispondenti in francese, spagnolo, portoghese, latino, greco, inglese, tedesco* [Vol. 5, pag. 284, **Poggiare**](https://archive.org/stream/vocabolarionauti05corauoft#page/284/mode/2up)